# spectral radius (adjacency matrix) of a partitioned graph

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Is the following bound on the largest eigenvalue of a partitioned graph
known?  It seems like it should be but I am not able to find a reference
to it.

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ whose vertices are partitioned into $V=V_1 \cup
V_2$ let $d_i(u)$ be the *internal degree* of $u$, the number of
neighbors of $u$ that are in the same partition and let $d_o(u)$ be the
*outer degree* of $u$, the number of neighbors of $u$ not in the
same partition.  So $d_i(u)+d_o(u)=d(u)$ for any vertex $u$.  Now
for either partition $S$ call $d_i(S)$, the internal degree of $S$, the
largest internal degree amongst the vertices of $S$.  That is, $$d_i(S)=
max_{u \in S} d_i(u).$$  And likewise for the outer degree of a
partition: $$d_o(S)= max_{u \in S} d_o(u).$$

If my sums are correct I bound the spectral radius of $A(G)$, the
adjacency matrix of $G$ by
$$\rho(G) \leq \max\{d_i(V_1),d_i(V_2)\} + \sqrt{d_o(V_1) d_o(V_2)}.$$

My question is whether, or not, this bound is already known -- assuming
I haven't messed up :-).  I cannot find any mention of it in the obvious
places (Godsil/Royle or Brouwer/Haemers).

Some comments.  The bound generalizes two common special cases: 1) if
$V_1, V_2$ is a bipartition then $d_i(V_1)=d_i(V_2)=0$ and we get a
version of the familiar bipartite graph bound; 2) if $V_2=\emptyset$
then we get the familiar maximum degree bound; Brouwer/Haemers discuss something similar (using interlacing and almost equitable partitions) but the emphasis there is on average degree, not maximum.

Many thanks.